# Conflict error while using revert command on a single-branch git tree

Tags: git

When I try to use simple `git revert <SHA_of_my_commit>` to return to a particular commit, I receive the following error message.

```
Auto-merging file1.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1.txt
error: could not revert 96882d9... second commit t2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

This is the result of git log:
[image]

No matter what commit I intend to come back to, I receive the same error message. How could I fix this error?

Comment: Worth noted : "use git revert to return to a particular commit" is already problematic language. This is *not* what the command is supposed to achieve. It creates a **new** commit on top, which happens to contain the reverse changes designated commit had. See it as "create evil twin commit" if the metaphor suits you.

Comment: Is there is changes you didn't commit when/before trying to revert ? If yes i think this changes are causing you the conflict.

Comment: @tawfiknasser no I checked. The tree is clean every time and when I revert it raises a conflict that needs to be manually fixed

Comment: It’s not an “error”! Merge conflicts are not an error. Just resolve the conflict and move on.

Comment: `**error:** could not revert 96882d9... second commit t2` @matt

Comment: @tawfiknasser What I'm saying is, I think git is wrong to call this an error. It's an error in the very technical sense that the command given has not been completed, and the user needs to take action before we can move on. But it is not a Bad. They could have omitted that line of the message and all would be just the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to revert last commit there shall be no issue unless you have uncommitted changes.

If you are trying to revert not the last commit you may face conflicts and this is normal when upcoming commits depends on a commit you want to revert.

[image]

`$ git revert [commit_2_SHA]` will add to the git tree another commit that contain the reverting of commit_2.

before creating the revert commit a **conflict** in the auto merge may happen between the revert commit and the HEAD and require you to manually fix it.

and this may happen simply because commit_3 depends(using/updating...) on changes you did in the revert commit.